# python unable to exit if the first for loop iteration matches

Tags: python

This is `file.json`:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Jennifer",
    "counts": 10,
    "available_days": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Wednesday"],
    "last_update": "2024-01-21T11:12:35.126945"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Joseph",
    "counts": 10,
    "available_days": ["Sunday", "Monday", "Wednesday"],
    "last_update": "2024-01-23T11:12:36.851668"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Mary",
    "counts": 10,
    "available_days": ["Sunday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"],
    "last_update": "2024-01-22T11:12:36.224657"
  },
  {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Saeed",
  "counts": 10,
  "available_days": ["Sunday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"],
  "last_update": "2024-01-25T11:12:37.875114"
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "David",
  "counts": 10,
  "available_days": ["Sunday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"],
  "last_update": "2024-01-24T11:12:35.746215"
  }
]
```

This is python code:

```py
today = 'Tuesday'
with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

times = []
for i in data:
    times.append(i['last_update'])

times.sort()

for days in data:
  for being_available in days['available_days']:
    for time in times:
      if time == days['last_update'] and being_available == today:
        print(f'Today is {days["name"]} turn.')
        break
```

This is the current output:

```
Today is Mary turn.
Today is Saeed turn.
Today is David turn.
```

While it should be (expected output):

```
Today is Mary turn.
```

I'm not sure which part of my code is wrong. Since `Mary`'s `last_update` is the oldest, then she should be printed only.

Comment: `break` only exits the loop that it is immediately inside. You have 3 nested `for` loops: the outer two continue after the `break` statement.

Comment: Also `today` doesn't seem defined?

Comment: @0stone0 I forgot, defined now.

Comment: @slothrop I tried using `break` statement in different indentations after the last `print`, but it prints nothing.

Comment: extract max value from times, and compare only against it, not all times

Comment: You're looping over all the people and print whether they are available on Tuesdays, since you loop over all times as well. Just step through the loops (by adding prints or using a debugger) to see the behaviour in detail.

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that you are iterating through each time for every person's available days, which is causing multiple prints. and the **break statement is applied to the inner loop but the outer loop is still on** Instead, you should find the person with the oldest last_update time who is also available on the given day.

- filter people who are available today
- sort the available people based on last_update time
- print the first person (oldest last_update) who is available today

### Edited Code

```py
# Filter people who are available today
available_people = [person for person in data if today in person['available_days']]

available_people.sort(key=lambda x: x['last_update'])

if available_people:
    print(f'Today is {available_people[0]["name"]} turn.')
else:
    print('No one is available today.')
```

### Output

```
Today is Mary turn.
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nesting `for`'s, you could keep track of the lowest date, and just skip the check if `today` isn't set in `available_days`:

```py
import json

today = 'Tuesday'

with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

name = None
date = None

for days in data:
    if not (today in days['available_days']):
        continue

    if not date or date > days['last_update']:
        date = days['last_update']
        name = days['name']

if not name:
    print('Didn\'t find somebody :(')
else:
    print(f'Today is {name} turn.')
```

Output:

> Today is Mary turn.